# Docker running out of memory

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2

I have some **Docker containers** running on an AWS EC2 instance. The containers are running Java **Spring Boot** applications. Intermittently, (every couple of weeks so far), it seems Docker runs out of memory. Sometimes, I can't even SSH back into the instance.

I've tried to look at the application log files within each of the containers to see which container is causing the issue, but I can't find any memory-related errors. In the Docker **log file**, I can only see errors saying:

> docker-containerd cannot allocate memory when the error happens.

How can I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Have you correctly limit the JVM to the Docker containers memory limits ?

Comment: I wasn't running with any memory restrictions but the more I read about it, I think I need too.

Comment: That means your JVM depending on the version of the JVM will pick up the memory limits of the docker host and not of the docker container which is wrong...See https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/official-docker-image-for-oracle-java-and-the-openjdk-roadmap-for-containers ...So you need to set the appropriate JVM parameters to limit the memory to the limit of the Docker container. Doing so will give you the chance to test the container locally and observe the JVM information (Spring Boot has metrics etc./memory information; So you have missed also to monitor the JVM inside the docker container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java programs are "well" known for eating up memory if your code has some design issues. First, try to configure the maximum heap memory and see how that's coming through.

Since you said,

> Sometimes I can't even SSH back into the instance.

I would try limiting Docker containers memory usage as well:

*[Limit a container's resources](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory)*

If your Java program crashes with out-of-memory, then I would profile the application and see where exactly memory is getting eaten up.

Comment: Thanks Joanna. I'll configure the memory in these two places. Hopefully then I can at least see which container is blowing. I'll also see if I can find some utility that periodically logs the container memory/CPU to AWS Cloudwatch so I can try to understand when the issue is happening.